# Postgresql ignoring 'when' condition on trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger, datagrip

A trigger seems to be ignoring the 'when condition' in my definition but I'm unsure why. I'm running the following:

```
create trigger trigger_update_candidate_location
after update on candidates
for each row
when (
  OLD.address1 is distinct from NEW.address1
  or
  OLD.address2 is distinct from NEW.address2
  or
  OLD.city is distinct from NEW.city
  or
  OLD.state is distinct from NEW.state
  or
  OLD.zip is distinct from NEW.zip
  or
  OLD.country is distinct from NEW.country

)
execute procedure entities.tf_update_candidate_location();
```

But when I check back in on it, I get the following:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create trigger trigger_update_candidate_location
  after update
  on candidates
  for each row
execute procedure tf_update_candidate_location();
```

This is problematic because the procedure I call ends up doing an update on the same table for different columns (lat/lng). Since the 'when' condition is ignored this crates an infinite loop.

My intention is to watch for address change, do a lookup on another table to get lat/lng values.

Postgresql version: 10.6
IDE: DataGrip 2018.1.3

Comment: It's not Postgres which ignores your intention, it's DataGrip fault.

Comment: @klin interesting, that doesn't surprise me - where did you learn that from?

Comment: Postgres is my friend for years and I know it cannot do such a silly thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly do you create and "check back"? With datagrip?

The `WHEN` condition was added with Postgres 9.0. Some old (or poor) clients may be outdated. To be sure, check in pgsql with:

```
SELECT pg_get_triggerdef(oid, true)
FROM   pg_trigger
WHERE  tgrelid = 'candidates'::regclass  -- schema-qualify name to be sure
AND    NOT tgisinternal;
```

Any actual `WHEN` qualification is stored in internal format in `pg_trigger.tgqual`, btw. Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html).

Also what's your current `search_path` and what's the schema of table `candidates`?

It stands out that the table `candidates` is unqualified, while the trigger function `entities.tf_update_candidate_location()` has a schema-qualification ... You are not confusing tables of the same name in different DB schemas, are you?

Aside, you can simplify with this shorter, equivalent syntax:

```
create trigger trigger_update_candidate_location
after update on candidates   -- schema-qualify??
for each row
when (
   (OLD.address1, OLD.address2, OLD.city, OLD.state, OLD.zip, OLD.country)
   IS DISTINCT FROM
   (NEW.address1, NEW.address2, NEW.city, NEW.state, NEW.zip, NEW.country)
   )
execute procedure entities.tf_update_candidate_location();
```

Comment: Yes with the console in DataGrip, I'm now updating the IDE to the latest version. Current search path is `entities` so it would actually be `entities.candidate` I didn't get anything back when I ran the select in your post.

Comment: Then test again without `AND tgqual IS NOT NULL` to also get triggers without `WHEN` qualification. I added a better test to get all user triggers with or without `WHEN` qualification.

Comment: Updating DataGrip didn't change anything, however I have re built the trigger with your syntax (plus `entities.candidates` schema), now when I run the select I get back the following which looks more correct

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_candidate_location AFTER UPDATE ON entities.candidates FOR EACH ROW WHEN (old.address1::text IS DISTINCT FROM new.address1::text OR old.address2::text IS DISTINCT FROM new.address2::text OR old.city::text IS DISTINCT FROM new.city::text OR old.state::text IS DISTINCT FROM new.state::text OR old.zip::text IS DISTINCT FROM new.zip::text OR old.country::text IS DISTINCT FROM new.country::text) EXECUTE PROCEDURE entities.tf_update_candidate_location`

Comment: That seems to be working as expected now, no infinite loop. This implies to me that the issue was my formatting in the original post.

Comment: Your original syntax is correct. Just needlessly verbose. If it was incorrect you would get an exception - or else you would see the `WHEN` condition when checking. My short syntax results in the same expression. Result looks correct now. (Only the casts to text (`::text`) are unexpected, shouldn't be there.) Any other tables named `candidates` in your DB, that might have been confused with `entities.candidates` to create this confusion?

Comment: Nope, they are genuinely text types so not entirely unexpected.

Comment: Casting `text` types to `text` is (mostly harmless) nonsense. In my local test with `text` types I see no such cast (as expected). No casts *at all* are needed for this trigger. Maybe another private idea of datagrip?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's the issue of DataGrip. Please follow the ticket to be notified when it's fixed.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7247